# Как заставить работать два javaскрипта на одной странице?

Tags: javascript

На странице 2 javaскрипта:

первый

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function getDocumentHeight(){
    return (document.body.scrollHeight >  document.body.offsetHeight)?document.body.scrollHeight:document.body.offsetHeight;
}
window.onload = function(){
    var anchorPos = document.getElementById('anchor').offsetTop;
    this.scroll(0,anchorPos);
};
</script>
```

и второй

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
function toggle() {
    var div = document.getElementById('pnlTest');
    if(this.checked)
        div.style.display = 'block';
    else
        div.style.display = 'none'
}
document.getElementById('chkTest').onchange = toggle;
}
</script>
```

При наличии второго скрипта первый отказывается работать. Как заставить работать одновременно оба скрипта?

Comment: То есть вместо window.onload=function()?
А то не могу найти window.onload=handler;

Comment: ну да, точно.

Comment: А как прописать правильно? Я меняю, но почему-то ничего не работает.

Comment: window.addEventListener('load',handler1);
    window.addEventListener('load',handler2);
    
    function handler1(){
        var anchorPos = document.getElementById('anchor').offsetTop;
        this.scroll(0,anchorPos);
    };
    
    function handler2() {
        document.getElementById('chkTest').addEventListener('change', function() {
            var div = document.getElementById('pnlTest');
            if(this.checked)
                div.style.display = 'block';
            else
                div.style.display = 'none'
        });
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо использовать

```
window.addEventListener('load',handler);
```

вместо

```
window.onload=handler;
```

потому-что так вы переписываете перехватчик события и выполняется только один.